How can I fix an error in discord.py with Loops (in Tasks)?
If I run my Discord bot I have this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):File "c:\Users\progi\Documents\GitHub\discord_bot\main.py", line 221, in <module>bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))^^^^^^^^^^File "c:\Users\progi\Documents\GitHub\discord_bot\main.py", line 207, in initself.check_empty_channels.start()File "C:\Users\progi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks_init_.py", line 398, in startself._task = asyncio.create_task(self._loop(*args, **kwargs))^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\progi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 417, in create_taskloop = events.get_running_loop()^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^RuntimeError: no running event loopsys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop._loop' was never awaited

I run my bot with this code (discord.py):
import os
import discord
import discord.ui
from worlds import *
from vars import *
from lists import *
from rule_checker import *
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord import app_commands
from discord import ActionRow, Button, ButtonStyle
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio

from env import *

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents, test_guilds=[1238156026054705182])  # Префикс для команд
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = bot.tree

error_embed = discord.Embed(description="У вас недостаточно прав на это действие!", color=embed_color)

#TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")

class Dropdown(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options = [
            #discord.SelectOption(label=" » Асгард", value=str(roleid3), emoji="️"),
            discord.SelectOption(label=" » Альвхейм", value=str(roleid1), emoji="‍♂️"),
            discord.SelectOption(label=" » Мидгард", value=str(roleid2), emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label=" ∥ Муспельхейм", value=str(roleid4), emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label=" ∥ Ванахейм", value=str(roleid5), emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label=" ∥ Йотунхейм", value=str(roleid6), emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label=" ∥ Свартальвхейм", value=str(roleid7), emoji="⚒️"),
            discord.SelectOption(label=" ∥ Нифльхейм", value=str(roleid8), emoji="☁️"),
            discord.SelectOption(label=" ∥ Хельхейм", value=str(roleid9), emoji="")
        ]

        super().__init__(placeholder="Выберите свой сервер",options=options)
    
    async def callback(self, inter: discord.Interaction):
        # Получаем пользователя, который выбрал опцию
        member = inter.user

        # Получаем ID роли из выбранной опции
        role_id = int(self.values[0])

        # Получаем роль по ID
        role = inter.guild.get_role(role_id)

        # Проверяем роль по доступным серверами к игре
        if role_id == 1238473654585786369 or role_id == 1238473033707028582:
            # Проверяем, есть ли у пользователя указанная роль
            if role in member.roles:
                # Если роль есть, убираем ее
                await member.remove_roles(role)
                await inter.response.send_message(f"> ❌ Роль <@&{role.id}> была убрана.", ephemeral=True)
            else:
                # Если роли нет, выдаем ее
                await member.add_roles(role)
                await inter.response.send_message(f"> ✅ Роль <@&{role.id}> была выдана.", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await inter.response.send_message(f"> ⚠️ Эта роль недоступна для вас!", ephemeral=True)



class DropdownView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_item(Dropdown())

class MyView1(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Асгард", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="️")
    async def second_button_callback(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=world2, ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Альвхейм", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="‍♂️")
    async def first_button_callback(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=world1, ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Мидгард", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="")
    async def five_button_callback(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=world5, ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Муспелльхейм", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, emoji="")
    async def six_button_callback(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=world6, ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Ванахейм", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, emoji="")
    async def tree_button_callback(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=world3, ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Йотунхейм", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, emoji="")
    async def four_button_callback(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=world4, ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Свартальвхейм", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, emoji="⚒️")
    async def eight_button_callback(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=world8, ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Нифльхейм", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, emoji="☁️")
    async def seven_button_callback(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=world7, ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Хельхейм", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray, emoji="")
    async def nine_button_callback(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=world9, ephemeral=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})')

    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name='scandworld.fun'))

    channel_with_buttons = bot.get_channel(1238168631091925012)
    async for message in channel_with_buttons.history(limit=None):
        await message.delete()
    if channel_with_buttons:

        # Отправляем сообщение с кнопками
        embed1 = discord.Embed(description='## Добро пожаловать в раздел миров! \n```Здесь вы можете почитать полезную информацию о всех существующих мирах нашего сервера.```\n *Для того, чтобы узнать о мирах подробнее, нажмите на кнопку.*', color=embed_color)
        await channel_with_buttons.send(embed=embed1, view=MyView1())
    else:
        print(f"Канал {channel_with_buttons} не найден.")

    channel_with_roles = bot.get_channel(1238168344000073802)
    async for message in channel_with_roles.history(limit=None):
        await message.delete()
    if channel_with_roles:

        # Отправляем сообщение с кнопками
        embed2 = discord.Embed(description='## Добро пожаловать в раздел ролей \n```Здесь вы можете получить роль любого мира, выбрав его из меню!``` \n*Выбор роли может помочь найти друзей для игры в вашем мире или помочь найти помощь!*', color=embed_color)
        await channel_with_roles.send(embed=embed2, view=DropdownView())
    else:
        print(f"Канал {channel_with_roles} не найден.")

@bot.command()
async def написать(ctx, *, text=None):
    # Отправляем сообщение от имени бота в тот же чат

    for role_id in moder_roles:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, id=role_id)
        if role:
            
            await ctx.send(text)
            await ctx.message.delete()
            return
        else:
            await ctx.send(embed=error_embed, delete_after=delete_time)
            return

@bot.command()
async def панелька(ctx, *, text=None):
    for role_id in moder_roles:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, id=role_id)
        if role:
            # Создаем Embed (панель) с кастомным цветом
            embed = discord.Embed(description=text, color=embed_color)  # Зеленый цвет

            # Прикрепляем изображение (если оно есть)
            if ctx.message.attachments:
                image_url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
                embed.set_image(url=image_url)  # Отображаем GIF как анимацию

            # Отправляем Embed от имени бота в тот же чат
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await ctx.message.delete()
            return
        else:
            await ctx.send(embed=error_embed, delete_after=delete_time)
            return


@bot.command(description="Информация о сервере")
async def инфо(ctx):
    # Отправляем сообщение только автору команды
    server = ctx.guild
    total_members = server.member_count
    online_members = sum(member.status == discord.Status.online for member in server.members)

    text = f'## Информация о {server} \n Айпи сервера: `scandworld.fun` \n Участников: `{total_members}` \n Онлайн: `{online_members}` \n\n## Полезные каналы \n Прочитайте правила: <#1238162480996286534> \n Выберите себе роль: <#1238168344000073802> \n Следите за новостями: <#1238481357676478536> \n\n *Связь с администрацией:* <#1238191924502990959>'

    embed = discord.Embed(description=text, color=embed_color)
    # Закомментировал удаление сообщения
    await ctx.send(embed=embed) #, delete_after=delete_time)
    #await ctx.message.delete()

@bot.command(description="Создать голосовой канал")
async def гс(ctx, channel_name="Г2С111", max_members=2):
    # Получаем сервер
    server = ctx.guild

    category = discord.utils.get(server.categories, id=category_id1)

    if channel_name == "Г2С111":
        await ctx.send(f"Нельзя создать канал без имени!")
    else:

    # Создаем голосовой канал с указанным именем и максимальным количеством участников в указанной категории
        channel = await server.create_voice_channel(channel_name, user_limit=max_members, category=category)

        await ctx.send(f"Голосовой канал '{channel.name}' с максимальным количеством участников {max_members}.")

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.check_empty_channels.start()

    @tasks.loop(minutes=5)
    async def check_empty_channels(self):
        # Замените на ID вашей категории
        category = self.bot.get_channel(category_id1)

        for channel in category.voice_channels:
            if len(channel.members) == 0:
                await channel.delete()

    @check_empty_channels.before_loop
    async def before_check_empty_channels(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))

# Запускаем бота с вашим токеном
bot.run(TOKEN)




I used any lines of code, but I don't know why this doesn't work. I check any posts, but I don't find any information. I search more information with copilot, but it didn't give me useful information.
What can I try next?

As an extension to the asyncio changes in discord.py v2.0, the loading and unloading of extensions and cogs is now asynchronous (read more).
This way you will need to load the MyCog in an async context as shown below:
import asyncio

# ...

async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
        await bot.start('TOKEN')

asyncio.run(main())

The asyncio.run() function will automatically create an envent loop for you, which prevents the RuntimeError: no running event loopsys error from happening when starting your task.
